# ERROR in Oracle Live SQL -> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle, live

```
'--create table dept(empid number(4) PRIMARY KEY ,ename varchar2(30) not null,sal number(6) not null,design varchar2(30),mgrid number(4),deptid number(2) not null);  
 --alter table dept add constraint C1 foreign key(mgrid) references dept(empid);

--insert into dept values(1005,'vivek',100000,'Director',null,30);
--insert into dept values(1004,'sumit',70000,'sr manager',1005,10);
--insert into dept values(1003,'amit',60000,'manager',1005,20);
--insert into dept values(1002,'shyam',30000,'clerk',1003,10);
--insert into dept values(1001,'ram',50000,'mgr',1005,10);

  select * from dept;

  select ename emp_name,ename reporting_off from dept dept3 ,dept dept4 where dept3.mgrid=dept4.empid(+);

  select ename emp_name,ename reporting_off from dept dept3 ,dept dept4 where dept3.mgrid=dept4.empid; '
```

> I tried changing the alias names but this doesn't resolve the issue. how can I rectify this?

Comment: Is that ename from dept3 or dept4? The database doesn't know

Comment: Please use real JOINs

Answer (score 1):

You are trying a self join here and when you select columns in the select list you have to `prefix` the table alias also along side the column when the column is present in more than one table mentioned in `from` clause.

In your example you are selecting column `ename` twice, one for the employee and one for the manager and because you have not prefixed the column from which table it should refer cause ambiguity here.

You already know the join condition and based on that prefix the columns as well which I presume something like,

```
select dept3.ename emp_name
      ,dept4.ename reporting_off 
  from dept dept3 ,dept dept4 
 where dept3.mgrid=dept4.empid(+);
```